# SSL_CTX_new crash only in 32 bit iOS devices with distribution build

Tags: c++, ios, multithreading, openssl

I have a very incomprehensible crash with my iOS application. The crash occures only on 32 bit devices (iPad 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 5c) with iOS 10 OS only in distribution build (debug builds and enterprise builds work without crash). My app was built with Xcode 11.3.1.

This is the call stack of the crashed thread:

```
#14. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  myapp                          0x6bf40c SSL_CTX_new + 3726105
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1db19237 szone_malloc_should_clear + 492
2  (Missing)                      0x145060f0 (Missing)
3  (Missing)                      0x2c2100b1 (Missing)
```

Call stack of all threads:

```
#0. com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1d5a2e94 getMethodNoSuper_nolock(objc_class*, objc_selector*) + 61
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1d5a2c91 lookUpImpOrForward + 296
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1d5a2b65 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 26
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1d5a91af _objc_msgSend_uncached + 14
4  UIKit                          0x23bc45d3 -[UIStatusBar _requestStyleAttributes:animationParameters:forced:] + 150
5  UIKit                          0x23bc4411 -[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animationParameters:forced:] + 468
6  UIKit                          0x23bc414d -[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animated:forced:] + 92
7  UIKit                          0x235ab8c7 -[UIStatusBar forceUpdateStyleOverrides:] + 90
8  FrontBoardServices             0x1fbdfcff __52-[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:]_block_invoke.27 + 166
9  Foundation                     0x1ec19421 <redacted> + 438
10 Foundation                     0x1eb9ac0f <redacted> + 66
11 BaseBoard                      0x1fb5e819 -[BSSettingsDiff inspectChangesWithBlock:] + 102
12 FrontBoardServices             0x1fbda027 -[FBSSettingsDiff inspectOtherChangesWithBlock:] + 90
13 FrontBoardServices             0x1fbdfb5d -[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:] + 300
14 UIKit                          0x237b502d __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 170
15 UIKit                          0x237b4cf3 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 824
16 UIKit                          0x23aba733 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 412
17 FrontBoardServices             0x1fbc9f67 __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.376 + 210
18 FrontBoardServices             0x1fbf4c13 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 18
19 FrontBoardServices             0x1fbf4acd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 220
20 FrontBoardServices             0x1fbf4db7 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cffdd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cfb05 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 424
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cdf51 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1e2211af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1e220fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
26 GraphicsServices               0x1f9cbb41 GSEventRunModal + 80
27 UIKit                          0x235a3a53 UIApplicationMain + 150
28 myapp                          0x39d26d main + 24 (main.m:24)
29 libdyld.dylib                  0x1da0e4eb start + 2

#1. APMExperimentWorkerQueue
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dace2fc fsync + 8
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7bacd1 (null) + 44054
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7c323b (null) + 2074
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7ba7fd (null) + 42818
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7abeb7 (null) + 16492
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7858fb (null) + 2524
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7a6e17 (null) + 51750
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e79a5ab sqlite3_step + 442
8  myapp                          0xf60a4d -[APMSqliteStore executeSQLStatement:error:] + 2979674
9  myapp                          0xf609e7 -[APMSqliteStore executeSQL:error:] + 2979572
10 myapp                          0xf5e0c7 -[APMSqliteStore ensureTableWithName:createSQL:requiredColumnNames:addOnColumns:error:] + 2969044
11 myapp                          0xf5d4b1 -[APMSqliteStore ensureTableWithName:elementaryColumnInfo:addOnColumnInfo:error:] + 2965950
12 myapp                          0xf5dcf9 -[APMSqliteStore ensureTableWithName:elementaryColumnInfo:addOnColumnInfo:modifyColumnInfo:error:] + 2968070
13 myapp                          0xf0ad95 -[APMEDatabase ensureAllTables] + 2628258
14 myapp                          0xf0a95d -[APMEDatabase initializeDatabaseResourcesWithContext:databasePath:] + 2627178
15 myapp                          0xf0a85b -[APMEDatabase initWithPath:] + 2626920
16 myapp                          0xf13047 -[APMETaskManager startTaskManagerOnWorkerQueue] + 2661716
17 myapp                          0xf12fd7 __35-[APMETaskManager startTaskManager]_block_invoke + 2661604
18 myapp                          0xf145d7 __46-[APMETaskManager dispatchAsyncOnWorkerQueue:]_block_invoke + 2667236
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9ee59d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e4b71 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#2. com.google.fira.worker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dace2fc fsync + 8
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7bacd1 (null) + 44054
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7c323b (null) + 2074
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7ba7fd (null) + 42818
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7abeb7 (null) + 16492
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7858fb (null) + 2524
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7a6e17 (null) + 51750
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e79a5ab sqlite3_step + 442
8  myapp                          0xf60a4d -[APMSqliteStore executeSQLStatement:error:] + 2979674
9  myapp                          0xf609e7 -[APMSqliteStore executeSQL:error:] + 2979572
10 myapp                          0xf5e0c7 -[APMSqliteStore ensureTableWithName:createSQL:requiredColumnNames:addOnColumns:error:] + 2969044
11 myapp                          0xf5d4b1 -[APMSqliteStore ensureTableWithName:elementaryColumnInfo:addOnColumnInfo:error:] + 2965950
12 myapp                          0xf5dcf9 -[APMSqliteStore ensureTableWithName:elementaryColumnInfo:addOnColumnInfo:modifyColumnInfo:error:] + 2968070
13 myapp                          0xf2a357 -[APMDatabase ensureAllTables] + 2756708
14 myapp                          0xf28d6f -[APMDatabase initializeDatabaseResourcesWithContext:databasePath:error:] + 2751100
15 myapp                          0xf1f897 -[APMDatabase initWithDatabaseName:persistedConfig:error:] + 2712996
16 myapp                          0xf31013 __47-[APMMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke + 2784544
17 myapp                          0xf30ae3 -[APMMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue] + 2783216
18 myapp                          0xf3072f -[APMMeasurement setEnabledOnWorkerQueue:] + 2782268
19 myapp                          0xf30605 __29-[APMMeasurement setEnabled:]_block_invoke + 2781970
20 myapp                          0xf4b531 __51-[APMScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 2892350
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9ee59d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e4b71 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#3. NSOperationQueue 0x145c36b0 :: NSOperation 0x145c3d10 (QOS: DEFAULT)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae2554 __ulock_wait + 24
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2a9d _dispatch_ulock_wait + 38
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2b9b _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f0b39 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 214
4  myapp                          0xb3be1 OnMain(void () block_pointer) + 70 (BlockTools.h:70)
5  myapp                          0xb3a81 +[UIDevice(Kit) is3DTouchSupported] + 75 (UIDevice_Kit.mm:75)
6  myapp                          0x3ecb13 -[DocumentAssetGenerator generateAssetsForDocument:] + 41 (DocumentAssetGenerator.mm:41)
7  myapp                          0x522fe1 -[DocumentImporter importDocumentNamed:atFilePath:toContext:document:] + 214 (DocumentImporter.m:214)
8  myapp                          0x4c9655 -[CoreDataSetup installPDFDocumentWithNames:atContext:] + 222 (CoreDataSetup.m:222)
9  myapp                          0x4c8e8b -[CoreDataSetup installOrUpdateMobileDataSheetInContext:] + 169 (CoreDataSetup.m:169)
10 myapp                          0x4c86fd -[CoreDataSetup installOrUpdateSampleDocuments] + 122 (CoreDataSetup.m:122)
11 myapp                          0x390f31 __51-[AppManager installSampleDocumentBundleIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 275 (AppManager.m:275)
12 Foundation                     0x1ec39b01 <redacted> + 8
13 Foundation                     0x1eb8faef <redacted> + 146
14 Foundation                     0x1eb81fe7 <redacted> + 770
15 Foundation                     0x1ec3bd39 <redacted> + 190
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9ee59d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e4b71 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#4. AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc6e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cfbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2ce065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2211af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1e220fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  AVFAudio                       0x348ab82f GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 142
7  AVFAudio                       0x348d458f CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 154
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8

#5. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc6e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cfbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2ce065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2211af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1e220fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  Foundation                     0x1eb75af5 <redacted> + 258
7  Foundation                     0x1eb9276d <redacted> + 86
8  UIKit                          0x23ea4ad9 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 128
9  Foundation                     0x1ec598eb <redacted> + 1122
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8

#6. com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc6e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cfbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2ce065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2211af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1e220fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  Foundation                     0x1eb75af5 <redacted> + 258
7  Foundation                     0x1eb9276d <redacted> + 86
8  myapp                          0xc6535 -[NSURLConnectionSyncAuth sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 26 (NSURLConnectionSyncAuth.m:26)
9  myapp                          0xc2ebf __51-[Reachability checkNetworkWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke + 315 (Reachability.m:315)
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9eeb1d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 536
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#7. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae273c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db968eb _pthread_wqthread + 1150
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#8. com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae2554 __ulock_wait + 24
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2a9d _dispatch_ulock_wait + 38
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2b9b _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f0b39 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 214
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9eeb1d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 536
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#9. com.apple.network.connections
0  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d9a4780 ccn_mul + 19
1  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d9bee47 cczp_mul_ws + 42
2  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d9bee47 cczp_mul_ws + 42
3  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d99c179 ccec_add_ws + 244
4  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d99c371 ccec_full_add_normalized_ws + 54
5  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d99db53 ccec_twin_mult + 1430
6  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d9bd32d ccec_verify_internal + 564
7  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d99dc95 ccec_verify + 104
8  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d99d36f ccec_pairwise_consistency_check + 168
9  libcorecrypto.dylib            0x1d99dd05 ccec_generate_key_fips + 22
10 libsystem_coretls.dylib        0x1da9ae39 sslEcdhCreateKey + 40
11 libsystem_coretls.dylib        0x1da9dc35 SSLEncodeKeyExchange + 264
12 libsystem_coretls.dylib        0x1da9f1f5 SSLAdvanceHandshake + 1708
13 libsystem_coretls.dylib        0x1daa358b tls_handshake_continue + 22
14 libnetwork.dylib               0x296e3097 __nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 + 52
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9ee59d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e4b71 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae1e7c __semwait_signal + 24
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1da360e9 nanosleep + 168
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x1d57392b std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > const&) + 102
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x221873c5 <redacted> + 148
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x22187207 <redacted> + 36
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x22187121 <redacted> + 118
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x22188197 <redacted> + 76
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x221880ed <redacted> + 18
8  JavaScriptCore                 0x2218832f <redacted> + 66
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96454 start_wqthread + 83

#12. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.work-queue :: NSOperation 0x1463a150 (QOS: DEFAULT)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae25c8 __unlink + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacedc5 unlink + 8
2  libremovefile.dylib            0x1da1770f __removefile_process_file + 82
3  libremovefile.dylib            0x1da1786b __removefile_tree_walker + 170
4  libremovefile.dylib            0x1da17a83 removefile + 102
5  Foundation                     0x1ebadcf5 <redacted> + 142
6  Foundation                     0x1eb81fe7 <redacted> + 770
7  Foundation                     0x1ebad8b1 <redacted> + 76
8  myapp                          0xe13dcf -[CLSFileManager removeItemAtPath:] + 58 (CLSFileManager.m:58)
9  myapp                          0xe1fa85 __71-[CLSReportsController prepareAndSubmitReport:asUrgent:withProcessing:]_block_invoke + 174 (CLSReportsController.m:174)
10 myapp                          0xe15a01 CLSApplicationAcivity + 161 (CLSApplication.m:161)
11 myapp                          0xe1f703 -[CLSReportsController prepareAndSubmitReport:asUrgent:withProcessing:] + 188 (CLSReportsController.m:188)
12 myapp                          0xe1c193 __62-[CLSCrashReportingController handleExistingFilesInProcessing]_block_invoke + 479 (CLSCrashReportingController.m:479)
13 Foundation                     0x1ec39b01 <redacted> + 8
14 Foundation                     0x1eb8faef <redacted> + 146
15 Foundation                     0x1eb81fe7 <redacted> + 770
16 Foundation                     0x1ec3bd39 <redacted> + 190
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9ee59d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e4b71 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#13. com.apple.usernotifications.UNUserNotificationServiceConnection.call-out
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae2554 __ulock_wait + 24
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2a9d _dispatch_ulock_wait + 38
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2b9b _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f0b39 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 214
4  myapp                          0x46e05b __42-[AppBuilder setupAppWithLaunchOptions:]_block_invoke_3 + 70 (BlockTools.h:70)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9ee59d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e4b71 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9eea1f _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 282
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#14. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  myapp                          0x6bf40c SSL_CTX_new + 3726105
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1db19237 szone_malloc_should_clear + 492
2  (Missing)                      0x145060f0 (Missing)
3  (Missing)                      0x2c2100b1 (Missing)

#15. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96454 start_wqthread + 83

#16. com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc950 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f291f _os_semaphore_wait + 16
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f2093 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3  CFNetwork                      0x1e8de6a1 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 256
4  CFNetwork                      0x1e8fe8bd +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 100
5  myapp                          0xc94bd +[ProxyCredentialRequestHandler uploadSharedCredentialStorageWithSystemCredentialsUsingURL:] + 308 (ProxyCredentialRequestHandler.mm:308)
6  myapp                          0x5a2ac7 __61+[AppBuilderWrapper configProxyCredentialRequestHandler]_block_invoke + 2560468
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9e1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9eeb1d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 536
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f01b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d9f000f _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9687d _pthread_wqthread + 1040
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#17. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae273c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db968eb _pthread_wqthread + 1150
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9645c start_wqthread + 8

#18. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  myapp                          0xe23d79 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1682054
1  myapp                          0xe23d79 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1682054
2  myapp                          0xe23fd7 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1682660
3  myapp                          0xe17639 CLSHandler + 26 (CLSHandler.m:26)
4  myapp                          0xe13aa1 CLSMachExceptionServer + 1615790
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8

#19. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dacc6e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cfbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2ce065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2211af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1e220fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  CFNetwork                      0x1e8fe393 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 402
7  Foundation                     0x1ec598eb <redacted> + 1122
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8

#20. GAIThread
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1e7bf4e0 sqlite3_bind_int64
1  myapp                          0xe0e1ff -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] + 283 (GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.m:283)
2  myapp                          0xe0db83 -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore upsertPropertyRecord:] + 229 (GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.m:229)
3  myapp                          0xe0d61d -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore nextHitNumberForTrackingId:clientId:] + 168 (GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.m:168)
4  myapp                          0xe07bdd -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueDispatch:] + 693 (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:693)
5  myapp                          0xe07a13 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueModel:] + 671 (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:671)
6  Foundation                     0x1ec59b2f <redacted> + 386
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cffdd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cfb05 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 424
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1e2cdf51 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1e2211af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1e220fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
12 Foundation                     0x1eb75af5 <redacted> + 258
13 Foundation                     0x1ebc2db9 <redacted> + 80
14 myapp                          0xdf6e39 +[GAI threadMain:] + 241 (GAI.m:241)
15 Foundation                     0x1ec598eb <redacted> + 1122
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8

#21. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96454 start_wqthread + 83

#22. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1dae1808 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db97c43 _pthread_cond_wait + 560
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db98fc5 pthread_cond_wait + 38
3  myapp                          0xbd37a7 void boost::asio::detail::posix_event::wait<boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock>(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&) + 107 (posix_event.hpp:107)
4  myapp                          0xbd3157 boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_event::wait(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&) + 89 (conditionally_enabled_event.hpp:89)
5  myapp                          0xbd28f9 boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) + 409 (scheduler.ipp:409)
6  myapp                          0xbd262f boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) + 154 (scheduler.ipp:154)
7  myapp                          0xbd1a7d boost::asio::io_context::run(boost::system::error_code&) + 70 (io_context.ipp:70)
8  myapp                          0xbd1a63 network::detail::AsyncExecutor::Run() + 20 (AsyncService.cpp:20)
9  myapp                          0xbd21bf network::AsyncService::Run(network::AsyncService*) + 140 (AsyncService.cpp:140)
10 myapp                          0xbd61bf decltype(std::__1::forward<void (*)(network::AsyncService*)>(fp)(std::__1::forward<network::AsyncService*>(fp0))) std::__1::__invoke<void (*)(network::AsyncService*), network::AsyncService*>(void (*&&)(network::AsyncService*), network::AsyncService*&&) + 4361 (type_traits:4361)
11 myapp                          0xbd615d void std::__1::__thread_execute<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(network::AsyncService*), network::AsyncService*, 2ul>(std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(network::AsyncService*), network::AsyncService*>&, std::__1::__tuple_indices<2ul>) + 343 (thread:343)
12 myapp                          0xbd5ad5 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(network::AsyncService*), network::AsyncService*> >(void*) + 352 (thread:352)
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9893b _pthread_body + 216
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db9885d _pthread_start + 234
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1db96468 thread_start + 8
```

Pods what i use in my app:

```
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14'
pod 'FirebaseDynamicLinks', '~> 4.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 4.3'
pod 'FirebasePerformance', '~> 3.1'
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig', '~> 4.4'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 6.4'
pod 'Former', '~> 1.8'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.17'
pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 5.0'
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 5.0'
pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.6'
```

Does anybody have an explanation, why does this happen only in distribution build with the previously mentioned device types? Thanks your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This crash was happened thanks to Xcode 11.4. Update Xcode to 11.5 beta or build your application with an older version of Xcode (<=11.3) can solve this issue.

Here is a thread about it:
https://forums.swift.org/t/crashes-on-32-bit-after-xcode-11-4/35035